# Ideas for a simple implementation of a volatile/temp table in Informatica

Tags: teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Mapping is: flat file is being loaded into a temp/volatile table, *no permissions to create stored procs on a database*.

I understand I can run a disconnected SQL Transformation, and just execute the "create table" from it. But since it's not a stored proc I do not see how I can run it preceding the file load (in the same mapping). Disk file is treated as a source, volatile table as a target.

Any ideas for a vanilla implementation of this, aside pre-SQL in the target object?

Comment: You did not mention database. Some database allow to create temporary table in tempdb zone. But if this is a problem then i think you can create a permanent table and truncate it using informatica. When you need a pre-defined table on a regular basis i think it is a good idea to create a permanent one.

Comment: I was looking for a session-long table, due to hard restrictions in the prod. environment; also more of an Informatica implementation, rather than database-specific

Comment: If I get this right you have a flat file with some data that you want to import into the database but you don't have an existing table to put your data into?
If that's the case the mapping itself in order to be valid will need some sort of a target table or a dummy file. If you don't have permission to create a table, I'm not sure how you will materialize the data at all.
Your option is a permanent table in the database. The volatile table won't work as well because they exist only until the session is open. After that, the table gets dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wouldn't use a temporary table at all.
Save the data you need to an intermediate file in the first Target Load Path in your mapping.
Then you can use this intermediate file in the second Target Load Path (and all following ones) within the same mapping with ease, be it as a source or as a LKP file.
And at the end of the session you simply delete the file in a post-session success command.